# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'projects')

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to push the API data to the array but I keep getting this error: "AddProject.vue Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'projects')". Any advice?

[image]

newData should be pushed to the array and from there I want to use the projects array to extract the API data.

Comment: you an arrow function instead of regular function

Comment: there seems no need to even define a function here. you can just use `async mounted`

Comment: Do not post code images but rather actual text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to create a new function in `methods`, just add your code (but make sure mounted is async):

```html
<script >
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      projects: [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    const data = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    const newData = await data.json();
    console.log(newData)
    this.projects = newData;
  }
}
</script>
```

You could do this:

```js
  async mounted() {
    this.projects = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(raw => raw.json());
  }
```

[Example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 3):

The error is that you are using `this` within a `function ()` notation. In order to make it work as you expect, you should use an arrow function.

```js
const test = async () => {
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, test() should be a method. Second, place the closing bracket in projects on the same line.